# Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.x changed behavior for assumenosideeffects

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-r8

I noticed a behaviour change using the Android Gradle Plugin 4.2.x regarding the ProGuard `assumenosideeffects` rule. I use this rule in my Android library project to remove all trace and debug calls from the SLF4J logging facility.

Using Android Gradle Plugin version 4.1.x the `org.slf4j.Logger.trace` method call is removed as expected from my wrapper class when building a release variant. To be more specific: The line of code is not available anymore in the classes.jar of the resulting AAR file.

Using AGP 4.2.x the line is still present. This is reproduceable by changing the version number from 4.2.x to 4.1.x with the setup below.

I added the `android.util.Log` dependency for testing reasons. The `d` method is removed after compilation in both AGP versions.

I would expect that the same rule works in both AGP versions.
What I'm missing here? Is there something needed in addition?

In addition, why is the rule working for the `android.util.Log` example but not for `org.slf4j.Logger.trace`?

Here's a setup to reproduce this scenario. Just create a new library project from scratch in Android Studio and add the following config where necessary.

project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.5.20"
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

module build.gradle

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.31'
}
```

Wrapper implementation

```
import android.util.Log;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyLoggerWrapper {

    private final Logger logger;

    private MyLoggerWrapper(Logger logger) {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public static MyLoggerWrapper getLogger(Class<?> clazz) {
        return new MyLoggerWrapper(LoggerFactory.getLogger(clazz));
    }


    public void trace(String message) {
        logger.trace(message);
    }

    public void anotherTrace(String message) {
        Log.d("MYTAG",message);
    }
}
```

ProGuard / R8 rules

```
-keep class com.example.myapplication.MyLoggerWrapper { *; }

-assumenosideeffects public interface org.slf4j.Logger {
    public *** trace(...);
    public *** debug(...);
}

-assumenosideeffects public class android.util.Log {
    public *** d(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar issue.  In my case the library is my own and R8 seems to refuse to remove my logging calls using assumenosideeffect.

My best result so far is to disable R8 when building the library using android.enableR8=false.

I'm not happy with this answer but it's the best that I have found so far.