# Kotlin DSL: Why am I able to get logs in release build from Play Store?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

We did not enable logging in release mode yet when we connect a USB cable and run Android Studio, we're able to get logs from release build downloaded from the store.

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )

            configure<CrashlyticsExtension> {
                // No need during development, enabling it also prevents Gradle to work offline
                mappingFileUploadEnabled = false
            }

            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("debug")
        }
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = true
            isShrinkResources = true
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )

            signingConfig = signingConfigs.getByName("release")
        }
    }
```

Do we need to explicitly disable logging in build variant when using Kotlin DSL?

For confidentiality this is a compact view of log, but these logs are pointing to app's package name. Running on Samsung A32 Android 13.

```
02:37:01.463  I  ViewPostIme pointer 0
02:37:01.563  I  ViewPostIme pointer 1
02:37:01.581  D  initGoToTop
02:37:01.594  D  [NativeCFMS] BpCustomFrequencyManager::BpCustomFrequencyManager()
02:37:01.631  I  Relayout returned: old=(0,80,1080,2274) new=(28,669,1052,1684) req=(1024,1015)0 dur=10 res=0x3 s={true 0xb400006f071bd800} ch=true seqId=0
02:37:01.632  I  mThreadedRenderer.initialize() mSurface={isValid=true 0xb400006f071bd800} hwInitialized=true
02:37:01.632  D  eglCreateWindowSurface
02:37:01.637  D   onsize change changed 
02:37:01.638  I  reportNextDraw android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals:4438 android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal:3116 android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run:10885 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1301 android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run:1309 
02:37:01.638  I  Setup new sync id=0
02:37:01.639  I  Setting syncFrameCallback
02:37:01.639  I  registerCallbacksForSync syncBuffer=false
02:37:01.643  I  Received frameDrawingCallback syncResult=0 frameNum=1.
02:37:01.643  I  Setting up sync and frameCommitCallback
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be mistaken, but you might need to add a proGuard rule to your `proguard-rules.pro`, something like:

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int d(...);
    public static int e(...);
    public static int i(...);
    public static int v(...);
    public static int w(...);
}
```

(source: [Removing Log call using proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218772/removing-log-call-using-proguard))

Comment: Wait really?! I thought logging is already disabled when setting `debuggable` to `false` but since it is already false in default release build type, then it is no longer to explicitly set it.

Comment: To be honest I always thought the same, but that seems not to be the true (I wonder if that has always been a case)

Comment: Will mark this as answer I just want to check it on other device first again because as I remember there is no logs before when running on release build but probably because it was installed via USB debugging. I check other related SO and it seems that this is really happening I am still in shock. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5553146/12204620

Comment: Believe me, I'm just as surprised :D

Comment: Dang! It is indeed do the logging! No freaking way!

Comment: Sorry the above code is not working, I still see logs despite other proguard rules is being applied.

Comment: Try the code from [this fairly fresh answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71484588/15749574)

Comment: Also, just checked in our project templates and we seem to be running a slightly different version `-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { public static *;}`, so try that as well

Comment: Unfortunately there still logs but I think it is coming from the library or modules. Despite my effort of putting `assumenosideeffects` rules in other module's proguard file, it is not working.